# Run a sudo command from CherryPy

Tags: python, linux, docker, cherrypy

I'm trying to create a small application with Python & Cherrypy. I need to interface Docker: list images, instantiate images etc. The background is probably not important. I just need to run some external commands (using subprocess) and process the outcome on the server side. Problem: you need to be root to run these commands. How to do it from a web server?

My code below works fine when I run the 'ls' command, but fails with the 'sudo docker images' command:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'sudo docker images' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

That command works fine when I ran it in a terminal and give the root password. So I need a way to elevate priveleges in the server. Sorry if I state this incorrecly, feel free to educate me. I'm a old linux user but not an IT person. I researched a bit how to do this and got no where...

Thanks for your help

Kind regards,
Nicolas

```
import subprocess
import cherrypy

def externalCmd(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode('utf-8')

class Webpages(object):
    def index(self):
        #self.images = externalCmd("sudo docker images")
        self.images = externalCmd("ls")
        return ''' Images ''' + self.images
    index.exposed = True

# run web server
cherrypy.engine.exit()
cherrypy.quickstart(Webpages(), config="webserver.conf")
```

The webserver.conf file contains the following:

```
[global]
server.socket_host ="127.0.0.1"
server.socket_port = 8080
server.thread_pool = 5
tools.sessions.on = True
tools.encode.encoding = "Utf-8"
[/annexes]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "images"
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It is dangerous to allow elevated priviliges for web apps.

Comment: I understand that. Only authorized users (login through the webapp) are able to run this particular command. If there's another way, I'm listening. How can run these commands from a web app? thanks

Comment: Well, as long as you know what you are doing, you can add the "user" that runs the webapp to the `/etc/sudors` by adding the line `webapp ALL = NOPASSWD: docker` where `webapp` is the name of the webapp account.

Comment: cool, thanks. I also managed by adding the user to the docker posix group. Like your suggestion too. thanks!

Comment: Great! It is probably better to do it the way you did, than adding to the sudoers file.